# Appropriate database for web analytics?

Tags: java, node.js, database, google-analytics, analytics

I am working on the Web analytics similar to [Google Analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/), and currently using [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

#### Problem using MongoDB

Writing and reading is performed at the same time, so after some point writing becomes slow. So I am looking for an appropriate database which suits the following requirements :

### Requirements

1. It should be Open Source
2. Is scalable, and can adapt large volumes of data
3. Better performance while aggregating data
4. Time based aggregation
5. Real time data processing
6. Has Driver support (clients) for Node.js and Java

#### The Database should be scalable with Node.js and Java

I am saving the data using Java, and fetching it via Node.js

Comment: You might ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for DBs that are designed for analytics. Those would be databases which support large amount of reads as well as writes on storage.
May be you should check these solutions:.

#### some opensource data storage solutions specific to realtime analytics

1. [Druid](http://druid.io/blog/2011/04/30/introducing-druid.html)
2. [Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/)
3. [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
4. [Hbase](http://hbase.apache.org/)
5. [hypertable](http://hypertable.org/)
6. [accumulo](http://accumulo.apache.org/)

**note:**
Here I think cassandra would have [appropriate drivers](http://planetcassandra.org/Download/ViewDownloads/ClientDriver) for languages that you are looking for and would be a good fit when you have large read and write operations. We can see cassandra being used in java/storm based projects which are aimed at real time processing.

#### reference:

1. http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis
2. http://relistan.com/cassandra-vs-mongo/
3. http://hypertable.com/why_hypertable/hypertable_vs_hbase_2/